# Syntax error, insert "VariableDeclarators" to complete LocalVariableDeclaration - Java ChooseYourAdventure game

Tags: java

I need some help with a Choose Your Adventure game I'm making in Java. I have four classes, three of which are written out below-- the last one is irrelevant for now.  In `Storyline`, `keySet()` does not seem to register that I have one `Storyline` object with a key called "key." I'm also having trouble figuring out scope for my `Storylines` class, as shown in `ChooseYourAdventure`. I get a

> "Syntax error, insert "VariableDeclarators" to complete LocalVariableDeclaration" and a "Storylines.s1 cannot be resolved to a type"

error when I call `Storylines.s1` in the main function. Additionally, the static `numberOfStories` variable does not seem to be incrementing when I call the `Storyline` constructor in the `ChooseYourAdventure` class outside of the main method. Any help solving any of these issues is much appreciated!

ChooseYourAdventure

```
public class ChooseYourAdventure {

    private static ChooseYourAdventure cyaGame;
    private static Character player;

    public ChooseYourAdventure()
    {
        ChooseYourAdventure cyaGame = new ChooseYourAdventure();
        Character player = new Character();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
//      while(player.checkIsDead() == false)
//      {
//          cyaGame.nextStoryLine();
//      }
        final Storyline s = new Storyline(0, 0, 0, "heyo", "key");
        Storylines.s1;
        System.out.println("key word: " + s.getKeyWord());
        Storyline.printStories();
    }
}
```

Storylines

```
public final class Storylines {

    private static final String text1 = "hey boi";

    public static final Storyline s1 = new Storyline(0, 0, 0, text1, "key");

}
```

Storyline

```
import java.util.HashMap;


public class Storyline {

    public static int numberOfStories = 0;
    public static HashMap<String, Storyline> stories = new HashMap<String, Storyline>();

    private int ageChange;
    private int happinessChange;
    private int meaningChange;
    private String text = "";
    private String keyWord = "";

    public Storyline(int a, int h, int m, String t, String k)
    {
        numberOfStories++;
        stories.put(this.keyWord, this);

        this.ageChange = a;
        this.happinessChange = h;
        this.meaningChange = m;
        this.text = t;
        this.keyWord = k;
    }

    public static void printStories()
    {
        System.out.println("number of Stories: " + numberOfStories);
        System.out.println("Keys:");
        System.out.println("stories.keySet() = " + stories.keySet());
        for(String k : stories.keySet())
        {
            System.out.println(k); // k is not showing up in keySet()?
        }
        System.out.println("Text:");
        for(Storyline s : stories.values())
        {
            System.out.println(s.getText());
        }
    }

    public int getAgeChange()
    {
        return this.ageChange;
    }

    public int getHappinessChange()
    {
        return this.happinessChange;
    }

    public int getMeaningChange()
    {
        return this.meaningChange;
    }

    public String getText()
    {
        return this.text;
    }

    public String getKeyWord()
    {
        return this.keyWord;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your intent with `Storylines.s1;` in your main method? Currently, s1 is just an object of type Storyline, it is not a method.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the StoryLines.s1 is expecting some value to be intialized that's why the compiler is giving you error.
Say for example,

```
 public class StaticClass {         
           static int value ;       
           public void show(){      
            System.out.println("Value:: "+value);   
          }
            public static void main(String[] args) {        
              StaticClass.value = 9;        //intialize value
              StaticClass sc = new StaticClass();       
              sc.show();    
        }
      }
```

same way you have to intialize value to Storylines.s1 in main method. It will not take the value from object intialized in Story class.